# findviewByid returns null for listview

Tags: java, android

Main activity
 List View returns a null value

```
  package com.example.dell.ab;

     import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.util.Log;
     import android.view.View; 
     import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
     import android.widget.Button; 
     import android.widget.ListView;
     import android.widget.TextView;

     import java.lang.reflect.Array;

     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     TextView textView;
     Button a, b, c, d;
    String deleteelement;
    ListView listView;
    String dataarray;
    Myadapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
            listView=findViewById(R.id.listview);


        }
     public void sh(View view)
     {

        Log.d("am"," "+textView);
        Log.d("am"," "+listView);
      dataarray=textView.getText().toString();
      adapter= new Myadapter(this,dataarray);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
 }
```

List activity. x ml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/texttobedisplayed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="score" />
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem here is `ListView` gives a null value
whereas text view which is a part of `activity.xml` whose code I did not put return a proper value

Comment: this line is problematic?: listView=findViewById(R.id.listview);

Comment: Looks like you've got the wrong layout. The `<TextView>` in the layout there has ID `texttobedisplayed`, whereas in the code, the `TextView` you say works was found with ID `textView`. Also, `MainActivity` is loading `activity_main`, but it looks like the layout you've posted is called `list_activity`, or something similar.

Comment: ya that seems to be returning null but findviewbyid(for textview )works fine

Comment: @MIkeM thats from a different layout thats working properly

Comment: What does that mean? If that layout is not `activity_main`, then you can't find that `ListView` in `MainActivity`.

Comment: read the question @MikeM

Comment: @AmeyBhivshet you need to clear your question read this comment of Mikem  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47530619/findviewbyid-returns-null-for-listview/47530735#comment82017733_47530619

Comment: I did read the question, multiple times, in fact, because it's not clear at all what you're saying. I'll try to explain it to you very simply: if the `ListView` with ID `listview` is not in `activity_main`, then you can't find it in `MainActivity`. You seem to be saying that the `TextView` with ID `textView` is working in `MainActivity`, so the layout you've posted is completely irrelevant here, unless you've just got them mixed up, as I said at the very beginning. Or, maybe you think you can access `View`s in other layouts not loaded, in which case, that's just incorrect.

Comment: @AmeyBhivshet share your  xml layout of **`MainActivity`**

Comment: @MikeM thanks  !!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Your connection to the XML file seems confusing. As you stated your XML file is called &quot;Last_activity.xml&quot; but in your main activity, you are setting the content view to activity_main. 
Second point which was already raised is that you are wiring your textview to a textview with ID of &quot;textView&quot; but in your XML you have assigned the textview with the ID of &quot;texttobedisplayes&quot;. In summary, I think you are communicating with the wrong XML file.
Is there a activity_main.xml file? If yes, please share the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CHANGE `INFLATED` `XML` and `TEXTVIEW` ID**

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texttobedisplayed);
listView= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration is wrong `listview` and text

```
textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texttobedisplayed );
listView= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
```

Comment: according to the latest version of studio  that statement is not necessary i guess I had tried what you are saying  but doesnt work

Comment: Since API 26 you don't longer need to explicit the type of view.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that your xml file name is differ from activity_main that you pass to setContentView. change the parameter you pass to this method to real file name.